# Is it possible to set a minimum width of a Div using a percentage as width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I currently have a `div` element that resizes to follow the window size, however I want it to stop resizing itself any smaller, using purely CSS. Is this possible, or should I use jQUERY?

```
div {width: 100%}
```

Basically what I have is the above, what I want to know is how do you set a minimum value in pixels? Like the below example:

```
div {min-width: 600px}
```

This doesn't appear to work as expected. The `div` does remain at the target width, but other percentage values utilized by elements within the `div` appear grow as the window shrinks in size.

Comment: where it did not work? Provide an example of it failing.

Comment: It does work, sort of. However, it seems to mess with other things that are using percentages for their widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work just fine. Check this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bc8ke0ca/

and notice the scrollbar as it appears once the width is less than 500px. I guess the problem will be somewhere else.

```
.myClass{
    background-color: #00eeff;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

N.B. when you comment the `min-width` property notice how the scrollbar disappears.

Comment: Alright, thanks. The issue is it adversely affects other elements in the div using a percentage, which should not happen since the width is the same after that point. I guess I'll have to keep looking.